# How Do you change cluster icon on tap for Google Maps?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I have a Google Map of GMSMapView Type and also I have markers shown on that map and I have also implemented Google clusters to that mapView.

So The thing I want to really achieve is that I want to tap on cluster icon and icon changes for a particular cluster. But currently that is not happening as when I tap on selected marker Only the individual marker does changes, but not the cluster Item does.

*My CLuster Group Shown On Map*

[image: My CLuster Map Image Link]

*What I really want to achive*

[image: What I want to achieve On Cluster Tap Image Link]

*what I have actually achieved for the individual marker.*

[image: what I have achieved for individual marker Image Link]

So the above image is of clustered markers I want to render an icon on that cluster item But unfortunately it’s not rendering as no image I am able to access in the delegates of **GMUClusterManagerDelegate** and **GMUClusterRendererDelegate**.
I am not getting any way how can I make a cluster icon change on tap action of a cluster marker.

**Note:- I want to change the icon on cluster tap for the cluster item And I have achieved for the selected individual marker**

Below is the code that I have done so far

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        propertyMapView.delegate = self
        createListOfPOIItems()
    }

    // MARK : -- Map related functions
//creating POOitems for the map
    func createListOfPOIItems() {
        self.propertyPOIItemList = []
        for index in 0..<self.propertyListModalArray.count {
            let propertylistmodal = self.propertyListModalArray[index]
            if UtilitySharedClass.sharedInstance.isvalidGeoLat(propertylistmodal.propertylat) && UtilitySharedClass.sharedInstance.isvalidGeoLong(propertylistmodal.propertyLong) {
                let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(Float(propertylistmodal.propertylat!)!), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(Float(propertylistmodal.propertyLong!)!))
                if universityLocation == coordinate{
                    continue
                }
                let item = POIItem(position: coordinate, name: propertylistmodal.propertyName ?? "", propertyListModal: propertylistmodal)
                self.propertyPOIItemList?.append(item)
            }
        }
        initiateClustering()
    }

    func initiateClustering() {
        // Set up the cluster manager with the supplied icon generator and
        // renderer.
        let iconGenerator = ClusterIconGenerator()
        let algorithm = GMUNonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm()
        let renderer = GMUDefaultClusterRenderer(mapView: propertyMapView,
                                                 clusterIconGenerator: iconGenerator)
        clusterManager = GMUClusterManager(map: propertyMapView, algorithm: algorithm,
                                           renderer: renderer)
        renderer.delegate = self
        renderer.minimumClusterSize = 2
        
        //renderer.animationDuration = 0.2
        
        // Generate and add random items to the cluster manager.
        generateClusterItems()
        
        // Call cluster() after items have been added to perform the clustering
        // and rendering on map.
        clusterManager.cluster()
        
        clusterManager.setDelegate(self, mapDelegate: self)
        
        self.setUniversityLocation()
    }
```

adding cluster for map

```
    /// adds property location to the cluster manager.
    private func generateClusterItems() {
        guard let items = self.propertyPOIItemList else { return }
        items.forEach({ (item) in
            clusterManager?.add(item)
            clusterManager?.cluster()
        })
    }
```

Implementing the delegates for the cluster

```
extension SearchViewController:  GMSMapViewDelegate, GMUClusterManagerDelegate, GMUClusterRendererDelegate {
    
    func renderer(_ renderer: GMUClusterRenderer, markerFor object: Any) -> GMSMarker? {
        let marker = CustomMarker()
        if let itemMarker = object as? GMUCluster {
            marker.markerType = .clusterType
            marker.markerCount = itemMarker.items.count
        } else if let itemMarker = object as? POIItem {
            marker.markerType = .itemType
            itemMarker.marker = marker
            marker.propertyListModal = itemMarker.propertyListModal
        }
        return marker
    }
    
    func renderer(_ renderer: GMUClusterRenderer, didRenderMarker marker: GMSMarker) {
        if let customMarker = marker as? CustomMarker {
            if customMarker.markerType == .itemType {
                let propertyMarker = createMarkerView(isSelected: customMarker.isSelected)
                propertyMarker.markerPriceLabel.text = customMarker.propertyListModal?.propertyPrice
                marker.icon = propertyMarker.asImage()
                marker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
            }
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - GMUClusterManagerDelegate
    func clusterManager(_ clusterManager: GMUClusterManager, didTap cluster: GMUCluster) -> Bool {
        let newCamera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: cluster.position,
                                                 zoom: propertyMapView.camera.zoom)
        let update = GMSCameraUpdate.setCamera(newCamera)
        propertyMapView.moveCamera(update)

        isClusterTapped = true

        clusterPropertyList = []
        let properties = cluster.items
        properties.forEach({ (property) in
            if let propertyModal = property as? POIItem, propertyModal.propertyListModal != nil{
                clusterPropertyList.append(propertyModal.propertyListModal!)
            }
        })
        
        if let previousMarker = propertyMapView.selectedMarker as? CustomMarker{
            previousMarker.isSelected = !previousMarker.isSelected
            let propertyMarker = createMarkerView(isSelected: previousMarker.isSelected)
            propertyMarker.markerPriceLabel.text = previousMarker.propertyListModal?.propertyPrice
            previousMarker.icon = propertyMarker.asImage()
        }
        self.propertyMapView.selectedMarker = nil

        self.propertyListContainerForMap.isHidden = false
        self.propertyViewForMapCollectionView.reloadData()
        return true
    }
    
    
    func clusterManager(_ clusterManager: GMUClusterManager, didTap clusterItem: GMUClusterItem) -> Bool {
        let newCamera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: clusterItem.position,
                                                 zoom: propertyMapView.camera.zoom)
        let update = GMSCameraUpdate.setCamera(newCamera)
        propertyMapView.moveCamera(update)
        
        if let previousMarker = propertyMapView.selectedMarker as? CustomMarker{
            previousMarker.isSelected = !previousMarker.isSelected
            let propertyMarker = createMarkerView(isSelected: previousMarker.isSelected)
            propertyMarker.markerPriceLabel.text = previousMarker.propertyListModal?.propertyPrice
            previousMarker.icon = propertyMarker.asImage()
        }
        
        let item = clusterItem as? POIItem
        if let tappedMarker = item?.marker as? CustomMarker{
            tappedMarker.isSelected = !tappedMarker.isSelected
            let propertyMarker = createMarkerView(isSelected: tappedMarker.isSelected)
            propertyMarker.markerPriceLabel.text = tappedMarker.propertyListModal?.propertyPrice
            tappedMarker.icon = propertyMarker.asImage()
            propertyMapView.selectedMarker = tappedMarker
        }
        
        isClusterTapped = false
        self.propertyListContainerForMap.isHidden = false
        self.propertyViewForMapCollectionView.reloadData()
        return true
    }
}
```

My POItem class

```
import Foundation
import GoogleMapsUtils
import GoogleMaps

class POIItem: NSObject, GMUClusterItem {
    var position: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var name: String!
    var propertyListModal: PeropertyListModel?
    var marker: GMSMarker?
    
    init(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D, name: String, propertyListModal: PeropertyListModel) {
        self.position = position
        self.name = name
        self.propertyListModal = propertyListModal
    }
}
```

class for IconGenerator

```
import Foundation
import GoogleMapsUtils

class ClusterIconGenerator: GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator {
    
    override func icon(forSize size: UInt) -> UIImage {
        let image = textToImage(drawText: String(size) as NSString,
                                inImage: UIImage(named: "clusterMarker")!,
                                font: UIFont(name: "Futura-Medium", size: 12.0) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12))
        return image
    }
    
    private func textToImage(drawText text: NSString, inImage image: UIImage, font: UIFont) -> UIImage {
        
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size)
        image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height))
        
        let textStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        textStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        let textColor = UIColor.black
        let attributes=[
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: font,
            NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: textStyle,
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: textColor]
        
        // vertically center (depending on font)
        let textH = font.lineHeight
        let textY = (image.size.height-textH)/2
        let textRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: textY, width: image.size.width, height: textH)
        text.draw(in: textRect.integral, withAttributes: attributes)
        let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return result!
    }
}
```

> **The above is the code I did so far but not worth please can you find me the way out how can I achieve the solution of rendering an icon on cluster Item marker on tap action.**

Comment: Even I am looking for a solution for this, the icon does not change on tap only when it it is rendered via cluster manager.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in changing the icon using buckets index
I guess for changing image you can use the code below. You can use the buckets index and show the cluster marker's icon respectively.

```
let iconGenerator = GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator(buckets: [5, 10, 15], backgroundImages: [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "clusterSelectedMarker"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "clusterSelectedMarker"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "clusterSelectedMarker")])
let algorithm = GMUNonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm()
                                                clusterIconGenerator: iconGenerator)
var renderer = CustomClusterRenderer(mapView: propertyMapView, clusterIconGenerator: iconGenerator)
clusterManager = GMUClusterManager(map: propertyMapView, algorithm: algorithm,
                                           renderer: renderer)
```

Comment: Your answer does makes sense But I want is that whenever I tap on cluster item the delegate gets called and however I want the cluster icon to get change